# How to control the folds of a cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I made pants using a cloth simulation. I pinned them to the waist of the model. The problem is that the pants keep folding inside. I want to take the cloth out like the function in Marvelous, but is there such a function in blender? Or what should I do?
[image]

[my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B8yQUbkNya2jQ4b-DP0KmfJOn4UqMoEY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please use titles that describe the problem clearly.

Comment: sorry. my bad english.